# Impact of a key store change on local user data

Tags: android, react-native, local-storage, android-keystore, android-update-app

I'm currently working with my team on an app update.

We chose to recreate the application from scratch. (App 2)

The old application (App 1) stores user information locally on their devices.

We have developed an update for the old version (App 1) which allows, via providing the user's email address, the recovery of their data and the application of their data to our new app which works via API (App 2).

The agency that created the old application (App 1) lost the key store and password. We need to apply the update but we need to change the key store.

My question is the following :

By replacing the key store and deploying the update, is there an impact on local user data? Will we recover user data?

Thanks in advance !

We updated the iOS version and the data transfer worked. For the android version, we are stuck. We cannot test since we do not have the key store and the key store password.

I looked through stack overflow but didn't find a similar case. Namely, the preservation and possibility of recovering local data